# Python: Getting None when trying to print

Tags: python

The code below is so simple, why is it printing None. Does that mean it's not finding the page?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

br = RoboBrowser()

login_url = 'https://www.cbssports.com/login'
login_page = br.open(login_url)

print(login_page)
```

Answer (score 1):

## `br.open` doesn't return the page content

`br.open` seems to open the robot browser to that page, which only changes the state of the robot browser. If you want to get the content of the page, you can do `br.open(login_url)` which opens the page, and then `print(br.state.response.text)`, which prints the text sent back in the response, which is stored in the state of the browser.